# What is this JSON Decoder piece of code doing?

Tags: python, json

I have been using this piece of code:

```
def read_text_files(filename):
    # Creates JSON Decoder
    decoder = json.JSONDecoder()
    with open(filename, 'r') as inputfile:
        # Returns next item in input file, removes whitespace from it and saves it in line
        line = next(inputfile).strip()
        while line:
            try:
                # Returns 2-tuple of Python representation of data and index where data ended
                obj, index = decoder.raw_decode(line)
                # Remove object
                yield obj
                # Remove already scanned part of line from rest of file
                line = line[index:]
            except ValueError:
                line += next(inputfile).strip()                    
            if not line:
                line += next(inputfile).strip()
            global count
            count+=1
            print str(count)

all_files = glob.glob('Documents/*')
for filename in all_files:
    for data in read_text_files(filename):      
        rawTweet = data['text']
        print 'Here'
```

It reads in a JSON file and decodes it. However, what I realise is that when I place the count and print statements inside the ValueError, I'm losing almost half of the documents being scanned in here - they never make it back to the main method.

Could somebody explain to me exactly what the try statement is doing and  why I'm losing documents in the except part. Is it due to bad JSON?

**Edit: Including more code**

Currently, with the code posted, the machine prints:

```
"Here"
2
3 etc...
199
Here
200 
Here (alternating like this until)...
803
804
805 etc...
1200
```

Is this happening because some of the JSON is corrupt? Is it because some of the documents are duplicates (and some definitely are)?

**Edit 2:**

Interesting, deleting:

```
line=next(inputfile).strip()
while line
```

and replacing it with:

```
for line in inputfile:
```

appears to have fixed the problem. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

The `try` statement is specifying a block of statements for which exceptions are handled through the following `except` blocks (only one in your case).

My impression is that with your modifications you are making a second exception trigger inside the exception handler itself.  This makes control go to a higher-level exception handler, even outside function `read_text_files`.  If no exception occurs in the exception handler, the loop can continue.

Please check that `count` exists and has been initialized with an integer value (say `0`).

Comment: It is initialised outside of the method. I'm just curious what's happening because when I put a counter in there, I have 1200 documents. When I put a counter outside the method, I only get 650. However, if I add this 650 to the total of "count" (i.e. the exception), I get the 1200 again - so I don't get why I'm losing the documents there